# Assembly Stack, Is this right?

Tags: assembly, return

I heard when you call a function, the only value guaranteed to remain the same is technically esp/ebp.  So if you have a value in %ebx and you call a function, you should not expect it to remain after the function returns.  However, what if you don't manipulate %ebx in the function, could the value potentially remain the same just because it wasn't touched in memory, and the address for registers always stay the same, so whatever value is in the address of %ebx will stay there?

And regarding return values, say I have this code:

```
movl $8, %eax
movl $8, %ebx
pushl $4
call function

function:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
imul %ebx, %eax
movl $4, %ebx
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

So the return value which is 8*8 is in %eax because it was put there in the other function, yet would 4 then remain in %ebx?  Or if I never moved anything into %ebx, would %ebx then remain 8?

I'm assuming this is blatantly obvious, but I want to be absoluetly sure so I don't form blatantly wrong conceptions either.

Comment: "Guaranteed to be the same" is not true for `ebp` and `esp` as you are free to change them. However, that will make your program crash. So the 'guarantee' is actually a mere *convention*, and it's the same for other registers.

Answer (score 2):

> So the return value which is 8*8 is in %eax because it was put there
>   in the other function, yet would 4 then remain in %ebx? Or if I never
>   moved anything into %ebx, would %ebx then remain 8?

Yes, registers keep their values until changed.
You normally have no intimate knowledge of the internals of a called function, so only the conventions specify what you can expect to be unchanged. Both the caller and the callee should agree on this, and be coded accordingly.